# how to open a link in another page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

in html code how to make  tag to open a link in another page ??

Comment: Misunderstood your question. I thought you meant a link that is already on another page. You want to open another window?

Comment: please mark one of the answers as correct unless everyone misunderstood your request.

Comment: If this question no longer requires additional answers, please mark the appropriate post as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If by "another page" you mean a new window:

```
<a href="/page.html" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

More targets here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Or you can read about it in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target if you prefer MDN to w3schools.

Answer (score 2):

Add `target="_blank"` to the tag's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you want to say target="blank". Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp)